# Show timestamps to CSS version of iMessages Interface

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an iMessages like view of some data showing outgoing and incoming messages - I found a nice CSS solution here:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/6mifhkdc

One missing part that I need is the ability to show the timestamps when messages were sent/received - like you get in iMessages when you swipe a message to the left. I have the timestamps stored and ready to display, I just need some guidance on the CSS to use to make them appear like they do in iMessages.

(the timestamps will appear permanently on the page - no swiping involved)

I'm a newbie at CSS so not sure where to start to add this type of attribute.

Here's a sample of how my page currently looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>fmSMS Chat Thread</title>


    <style type="text/css">

    /* Bit of normalisation */
    /*  Inspired by: http://cssdeck.com/labs/6mifhkdc */

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #222;
    font: 0.8125em/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    padding: 40px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

/* .bubble */

.bubble {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.25, rgb(210,244,254)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(149,194,253))
);
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* vendor rules */
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* vendor rules */
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* vendor rules */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
    border-radius: 20px / 10px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.bubble:before {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: -7px;
    z-index: -2;
}

.bubble:after {
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #d2f4fe;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: -5px;
}

.bubble--green {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.25, rgb(172,228,75)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(122,205,71))
);
    float: right;
}

.bubble--green:before {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px / 10px;
    left: auto;
    right: -7px;
}

.bubble--green:after {
    border-bottom-color: #ace44b;
    border-radius: 20px / 10px;
    left: auto;
    right: -5px;
}



    </style>

  </head>

  <body>


  <div class="container">


    <div class="bubble">
        This is a sample outgoing message
    </div>

    <div class="bubble bubble--green">
        Here's the first reply
    </div>

    <div class="bubble">
        Here's the next sent message
    </div>

    <div class="bubble bubble--green">
        And the final reply
    </div>


</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you putting the time stamp in your HTML? Is your question how to *add* a time stamp (your question's title, and depends on how you insert the messages) or how to *show* a time stamp by swiping to the left (your question body, and depends on the created HTML)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I have the timestamps stored ready to display, so my question is how to show them like they appear in iMessages. No swiping is involved, I just want them to appear permanently on the page in the same format as they appear in iMessages.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use CSS to add timestamps. Generate the timestamp from javascript or get it from the API and then add it to your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

First *add* the timestamp to your application using the Javascript attribute `Date.now`. *Then* make it look pretty using CSS. 
CSS will only control the way elements *look* in your application, it's not the language to use to add elements to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Found this which was close to what I was after:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pmbrpxle